# Rock Paper Scissors game is not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I've been trying to figure out what is going on with my JavaScript that is not working. I'm a beginner and just started learning JavaScript a week ago. I've went through every question here regarding this but I'm still stuck and can't figure this out. This is my and HTML JavaScript code. My buttons aren't functioning, and this code just doesn't do anything.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const container = document.querySelector("#results-container");
const playerScore = document.querySelector("#user-score");
const computerScore = document.querySelector("#computer-score");
const scoreLabel = document.querySelector("#score-label");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);

    if (playerScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
      declareWinner();
    }
  });
});
const myArray = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

function computerPlay() {
  return myArray[~~(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  computerSelection = computerPlay().toLowerCase();;
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase()

  if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
    if (computerSelection === 'raper') {
      displayResult('You Lose! Paper beats Rock');
    } else if (computerSelection === 'scissors') {
      displayResult('You Win! Rock beats Scissors');
    } else {
      displayResult("It's a tie");
    }
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div id="rockbutton" class="button">
    <img src="rocks.jpg" alt="rock" height="30px">
  </div>
  <div id="paperbutton" class="button">
    <img src="papers.jpg" alt="paper" height="30px">
  </div>
  <div id="scissorsbutton" class="button">
    <img src="scissors.jpg" alt="scissor" height="30px">
  </div>
  <div id="score-label">

    <p class="label1">you</p>
    <p class="label2">computer</p>
    <div id="score-container">
      <div id="player-score" class="score">0</div>
      <div class="player-selection"></div>
      <div id="computer-score" class="score">0</div>
      <div class="computer-selection"></div>
      <div id="results-container"></div>
    </div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" about it? Describe the specific error you have

Comment: Can you add your HTML code so I can test and run it?

Comment: Under the assumption of not a typo, pretty sure `raper` won't match anything.

Comment: My buttons aren't functioning, and this code just doesn't do anything. I've been trying to make it to function for 2 days now., but nothing works. @CertainPerformance

Comment: I just did. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm a beginner, and still learning. @EarlyBird

Comment: @pal hi. Do you know how to access the browser console? If so, can you open it and tell us if you see any error messages in it?

Comment: it says 'uncaught syntax error'. @EKW

Comment: @pal Please paste the entire error into your post.

Comment: Your braces are not balanced. You're missing several `}` at the end of `playRound`.

Comment: And your HTML tags don't match. You're missing some `</div>` and you have `</main>` without `<main>`

Answer (score 0):

I got kind of obsessed fiddling with this while watching tv. There's probably some really clever way to determine a winner with bitwise flags or something, but this is nice and simple. Someone else can replace the computer move with Machine Learning.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("scores");
  const output = document.querySelector("#output");
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  buttons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", clicked));
  const history = [];
  const scores = {
    p: 1,
    c: 1
  };

  const scoreChart = displayScores(scores, ctx);

  function clicked(event) {
    const pthrow = event.target.id;
    const cthrow = chooseThrow(history);
    const winner = determineWinner(pthrow, cthrow);
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const round = {
      pthrow,
      cthrow,
      winner,
      timestamp
    };
    history.push(round);
    displayResult(scores, scoreChart, output, round);
  }
});

function determineWinner(pthrow, cthrow) {
  if (pthrow === cthrow) return "t";
  else if (pthrow == "r") return cthrow == "p" ? "c" : "p";
  else if (pthrow == "p") return cthrow == "s" ? "c" : "p";
  else if (pthrow == "s") return cthrow == "r" ? "c" : "p";
}

function getThrowLabel(code) {
  return {
    r: "Rock",
    p: "Paper",
    s: "Scissors"
  }[code];
}

function getResultLabel(code) {
  return {
    t: "tie.",
    p: "win!",
    c: "lose."
  }[code];
}

function displayResult(scores, scoreChart, output, round) {
  if (round.winner === "c") scores.c++;
  if (round.winner === "p") scores.p++;

  updateScores(scores, scoreChart);
  displayText(output, round);
}

function displayScores(scores, ctx) {
  return new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: {
      labels: ["Player", "Computer"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [scores.p, scores.c],
        backgroundColor: ["rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(255, 99, 132)"],
      }, ],
    },
    options: {
      rotation: 0.5 * Math.PI,
    },
  });
}

function updateScores(scores, chart) {
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = [scores.p, scores.c];
  chart.update();
}

function displayText(output, round) {
  // TODO: yack about player history to make them think

  output.append(`You threw ${getThrowLabel(round.pthrow)}\n`);
  output.append(`Computer threw ${getThrowLabel(round.cthrow)}\n`);
  output.append(`You ${getResultLabel(round.winner)}\n`);
  output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;
}

function chooseThrow(_history) {
  // TODO: use history to choose a better throw?

  // pick one at random
  return ["r", "p", "s"][~~(Math.random() * 3)];
}
```

```css
#scoresContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

#output {
  white-space: pre;
  height: 72px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Roshambo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns">
      <button id="r">Rock</button>
      <button id="p">Paper</button>
      <button id="s">Scissors</button>
      <div class="row" id="output"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
      <h5>Scores</h5>
      <div id="scoresContainer">
        <canvas id="scores" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```